How to avoid stdout and stderr out-of-order when pipe is used?
Initially, I want to log a program (actually rsync, or diff, or others, illustrated by function prog() below) standard output, standard error, and combined output and error (namely stdall) into separate files.
(eval is needed in my actual script.)
#!/bin/sh

prog() {
    echo 1
    echo 2 >> /dev/stderr
    echo 3
    echo 4 >> /dev/stderr
}

rm -f std*.output

{
{
{
    echo Going to run prog
    eval ' prog'
}                | tee -a stdout.output
} 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a stderr.output
}      2>&1      | tee -a stdall.output
echo ---------------------
tail -vn +1 -- *

The output is:
2
4
Going to run prog
1
3
---------------------
==> stdall.output <==
2
4
Going to run prog
1
3

==> stderr.output <==
2
4

==> stdout.output <==
Going to run prog
1
3

Please note that in both the console output and the stdall.output file, the lines are out-of-order. stderr (2, 4) is printed before stdout (Log message, 1, 3).
We can simplify the above script into just | cat - which can also illustrate the same problem.
#!/bin/sh

prog() {
    echo 1
    echo 2 >> /dev/stderr
    echo 3
    echo 4 >> /dev/stderr
}

{
    echo Going to run prog
    eval ' prog'
} | cat -

The output is: (Note it is out-of-order.)
2
4
Going to run prog
1
3

Incidentally, I found that adding | cat - to the status message, and adding a blank standard error at the end, can make the output back into proper order.
#!/bin/sh

prog() {
    echo 1
    echo 2 >> /dev/stderr
    echo 3
    echo 4 >> /dev/stderr
}

{
    echo Going to run prog | cat -      # fix, dont know why
    eval ' prog'
    printf '' >> /dev/stderr            # fix, dont know why
} | cat -

The output is in proper order:
Going to run prog
1
2
3
4

Why, when pipe is used, the stdout and stderr became out-of-order in the first place? How does it work? How to properly avoid stdout and stderr out-of-order when pipe is used? My trial above is just unproved trial-and-error. Why did the trail fix the problem?

> /dev/stderr is wrong on Linux/Cygwin. Use >&2 instead.

@StéphaneChazelas - Thanks for spotting them. More confusingly, changing into >&2 makes the order changes in every execution.

Once stdout and stderr are two different pipes, there's no way to know the order prog will have written the messages to each.
And if you make it the same pipe, then there's no way to differentiate stdout and stderr messages.
Some options could be:

Convince prog to whenever it sends something to stdout or stderr, duplicate it to another fd so you can do prog > out 2> err 3> both.
Convince prog to "decorate" the stdout and stderr writes so you can tell which is which. For instance, instead of sending hello to stdout, send {"out":"hello"} so running prog 2>&1 | dispatcher out err both would allow the dispatcher to extract output, errors and send  to corresponding files in the write order.
Convince prog to do line-based output and timestamp or number all lines so getting out+err would be just a merge-sort (prog > out-pipe 2> err-pipe & sort -m <(tee < out-pipe out) <(tee < err-pipe err)).

If you can modify prog, it can be relatively easy.
1 has the potential to be the one with least overhead overall and with your example could look like:
out() if [ "$#" -gt 0; then
  printf    '%s\n' "$@"
  printf>&3 '%s\n' "$@"
fi
err() if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  printf>&3 '%s\n' "$@"
fi
prog() {
  out 1
  err 2
  out 3
  err 4
}

But could soon become tricky in the general case. In a shell script, any command you run would need to play along with that game. In a C or other general programming language, it's complicated by the fact that they don't directly call the write() system call, but some other framework such as stdio that usually delay the output via buffering.
3 has the benefit of restoring the intended order of messages even in cases where errors jump the queue because stdout is buffered.
If you can't modify prog, then it becomes tricky as you can't even really use $LD_PRELOAD tricks because of the fact that applications generally don't call write() directly but generally stdio functions (all in the libc, so hijacking write() in $LD_PRELOAD won't affect the stdio functions).
You'd have to hijack the writing system calls.
From an external point of view, it's also hard to tell which write is meant to be a stdout or stderr write. In your example, in echo 2 >> /dev/stderr, echo writes its output to fd 1 which has been opened in append mode to the same file as stderr points to. How would a $LD_PRELOAD injector know it's meant to be a stderr write? Even if we change it to echo 2 >&2 where at least the write() is done to the stderr open file description, it's still written there via fd 1.
Here, you could do a variant of 2, by using strace to somehow intercept the writing system calls:
out_file=out err_file=err out_err_file=both
strace -qqqf -a0 -s0 \
       -P "$(realpath -- "$out_file")" \
       -P "$(realpath -- "$err_file")" \
       -o >(
         perl -ne 'print pack("H*", substr($_, 10, 48) =~ s/ //gr) if
                     /^ \|/' > "$out_err_file"
       ) \
       -e write=all \
       -e %desc \
       prog > "$out_file" 2> "$err_file"

Where we have prog's stdout going to out, its stderr going to err, and strace traces the writes that are being made to the out and err files (which will be traced in the order prog makes them) which we get perl to decode into both.
That assumes prog doesn't write into its stdout/stderr files via splice() or mmap() where there would nothing for strace to see. If it lseeks() around in those files, that won't be reflected in both. I've only checked it works with processes that use the write() system call to write to stdout/stderr, I'm not sure whether it works as well with send(), writev(), pwrite()... but those would be far less common for writing to stdout/stderr.
Also beware that once their stdout no longer goes to a tty device like when it goes to a pipe or here to the out regular file, applications tend to switch from line buffering to block buffering while stderr remains unbuffered. That would affect the ordering of the messages. You may be able to use things like stdbuf -oL to revert to line buffering for stdout.
If you want prog's output and errors to go to the original stdout/stderr in addition to those out/err/both files, that's even trickier, especially if stdout and stderr go to the same file or even same open file description as is typically the case when run from a terminal where all of stdin / stdout / stderr are the result of opening the tty device in read+write mode.
All strace could really go with is which fd the writes are made to (1 for stdout, 2 for stderr), and while that would work for a normal program, that wouldn't in the echo foo >&2 case (as opposed to print -u2 foo of Korn-like shells) or your echo 2 >> /dev/stderr where the writes are done on fd 1.
You can give it a try for your actual prog:
out_file=out err_file=err out_err_file=both

strace -qqqf -a0 -s0 \
       -o >(
         perl -ne '
           BEGIN{open BOTH, ">&=3"}
           if (/^\d+\s+\w+\(([12]),/) {
             $out = $1 == 1 ? *STDOUT : *STDERR;
           } elsif (/^ \|/) {
             $text = pack("H*", substr($_, 10, 48) =~ s/ //gr);
             print $out $text;
             print BOTH $text;
           }' > "$out_file" 2> "$err_file" 3> "$out_err_file"
       ) \
       -e write=1,2 \
       -e %desc \
       prog

Where perl extracts from strace's 1234 write(fd, ""..., n) = n traces whether the system calls are made on fd 1 or 2 to decide where to send the decoded message.

Note the standard library's buffering of stdout may in practice defeat the strace mechanism (and is the most common reason for stderr/stdout getting out of order in my experience)

@abligh I do already mention the change of stdout stdio buffering when it doesn't go to a terminal device and the stdbuf -oL work-around. strace is not really defeated in that it logs the out+err in the exact order prog writes it, it's just that prog may change the order in which it writes message when stdout is redirected. The last command is not affect as prog's output is not redirected there.
